# "ARRAY_ROW parameter 2 mismatched row size" despite only referencing 3 rows?

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I'm using Google Sheets and trying to filter raw data based on a couple of basic criteria, whilst also interjecting the results with URL creation in Col4 and an image display in Col14 (each based on the results in Col3 and Col13).

However, when using this formula, if two or more rows meet the 'where' criteria, I am given a `ARRAY_ROW parameter 2 mismatched row size` error. When I search around for help with this error, I see lots of results about people referencing multiple different data sets with varying row amounts. But as we can see here, I only reference the same 3 rows each time.

Am I missing something with regards to this error?

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({
({
QUERY({A4:S6}, "select Col1,Col2,Col3 where Col15 = 'Review' and Col19 >=3",0)
}),({
HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("http://www.google.com/search?q=",INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(D4),COLUMN(D4)-1))),INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(D4),COLUMN(D4)-1)))
}),({
QUERY({A4:S6}, "select Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9,Col10,Col11,Col12,Col13 where Col15 = 'Review' and Col19 >=3",0)
}),({
IMAGE(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(N4),COLUMN(N4)-1)))
}),({
QUERY({A4:S6}, "select Col15,Col16,Col17,Col18 where Col15 = 'Review' and Col19 >=3",0)
  })
})
```

EDIT: Here's an example sheet of what I'm trying to achieve.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dwuvK-zxG1dqsWopaWkW69yT2M2dqopCs1sTw0-xNCo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Apologies, here is an example of what I'm trying to achieve:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dwuvK-zxG1dqsWopaWkW69yT2M2dqopCs1sTw0-xNCo/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=FILTER(A3:S5; O3:O5<>"Ignore")
```

[image]

Comment: That worked perfectly, and was so simple too! Thank you very much for your help.